# Add color to edge using igraph in R

Tags: r, igraph

I'm trying to get the links to each node to have the same color as the node itself. However, I've not been able to find any way to accomplish this while still keeping the amount of connections visible.

The code and the output:

```
library(igraph)

net <- graph_from_data_frame(d = send_rec, directed = TRUE, vertices = NULL)

colrs <- c("deepskyblue1","firebrick2","chartreuse1","yellow1","chocolate1","blueviolet")

plot(net, layout=layout.circle, vertex.color= colrs, main="circle")
```

[image: network analysis]

Ideally the gray lines would become the color of the node they are coming from while not just becoming one solid line.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get much nicer plotting results with a wider range of customization options if you use the `ggraph` package.

Obviously, we don't have your data, but using a similar graph from made-up data (see below), we can do:

```r
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)
library(tidygraph)

net <- graph_from_data_frame(d = send_rec, directed = TRUE, vertices = NULL)

colrs <- c("deepskyblue1","firebrick2","chartreuse1",
           "yellow1","chocolate1","blueviolet")

as_tbl_graph(net) %>% 
  activate(edges) %>% 
  mutate(to_name = .N()$name[to], 
         from_name = .N()$name[from]) %>%
  ggraph(layout = "linear", circular = TRUE)  +
  geom_edge_fan(aes(color = from_name), alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_node_circle(aes(fill = name, r = 0.2)) +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name), fontface = "bold") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colrs, guide = "none") +
  scale_edge_color_manual(values = colrs, guide = "none") +
  theme_graph() +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Reproducible example data**

```r
set.seed(1)

dept <- c("Admin", "Engineering", "IT", "Marketing", "Operations", "Sales")

send_rec <- data.frame(from = factor(sample(dept, 400, TRUE)), 
                       to   = factor(sample(dept, 400, TRUE)))

send_rec <- send_rec[send_rec$from != send_rec$to,]
```